# How to create parameterized test with few enums in JUnit 5?

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, junit5, parameterized-tests

For example, I have few enums in my project:

- Figure, with values TRIANGLE and SQUARE
- Color, with values are RED and YELLOW

How to create a test, using the cartesian product of all of the combinations? The follow code doesn't work:

```
// this doesn't work
@ParameterizedTest
@EnumSource(value = Figure.class)
@EnumSource(value = Color.class)
void test(Figure figure, Color color) {
    System.out.println(String.format("%s_%s",figure,color));
}
```

I want to get all of combinations:

```
TRIANGLE RED
TRIANGLE YELLOW
SQUARE RED
SQUARE YELLOW
```

My temporary solution is using annotation @MethodSource

```
// this works
@ParameterizedTest
@MethodSource("generateCartesianProduct")
void test(Figure figure, Color color) {
    System.out.println(String.format("%s_%s",figure,color));
}


private static Stream<Arguments> generateCartesianProduct() {
    List<Arguments> argumentsList = new ArrayList<>();

    for(Figure figure : Figure.values()) {
        for(Color color : Color.values()) {
            argumentsList.add(Arguments.of(figure,color));
        }
    }

    return argumentsList.stream();
}
```

But I don't want to have extra code in my tests. Has JUnit 5 any solution for my problem?

Comment: that would be useful but I don't think there is a better solution that the one you came up with

Comment: See https://github.com/junit-team/junit5/issues/1427

Answer (score 5):

[JUnit Pioneer](https://github.com/junit-pioneer/junit-pioneer) comes with [`@CartesianTest`](https://junit-pioneer.org/docs/cartesian-product/):

```java
import org.junitpioneer.jupiter.cartesian.CartesianTest;
import org.junitpioneer.jupiter.cartesian.CartesianTest.Enum;

class FigureAndColorTest {

    enum Figure {
        TRIANGE, SQUARE
    }

    enum Color {
        RED, YELLOW
    }

    @CartesianTest
    void test(@Enum Figure figure, @Enum Color color) {
        System.out.printf("%s %s%n", figure, color);
    }

}
```

Output:

```
TRIANGE RED
TRIANGE YELLOW
SQUARE RED
SQUARE YELLOW
```

**DISCLAIMER:** I'm one of the maintainers of JUnit Pionner.